# Redirect after signout in Angular 2 firebase?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

In the logout() function it is not navigating to 'add-listing'
Showing that ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined?
Please help

This is my component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
    router: any;
  user: Observable<firebase.User>;

  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { 
     this.user = afAuth.authState;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  login(){
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }
  logout(){
    debugger;
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
    this.router.navigate(['/add-listing']);
    console.log(this.afAuth);
  }

}
```

Comment: You've not injected the router into the constructor.

Comment: Thank u very much sir,I got it